# How can I disable PHP magic quotes at runtime?

Tags: php, runtime, magic-quotes

I'm writing a set of PHP scripts that'll be run in some different setups, some of them shared hosting with magic quotes on (the horror).  Without the ability to control PHP or Apache configuration, can I do anything in my scripts to disable PHP quotes at runtime?

It'd be better if the code didn't assume magic quotes are on, so that I can use the same scripts on different hosts that might or might not have magic quotes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only [*magic_quoted_runtime*](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) can be disabled at runtime. But [*magic_quotes_gpc*](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) can’t be disabled at runtime ([*PHP_INI_ALL*](http://php.net/configuration.changes.modes) changable until PHP 4.2.3, since then [*PHP_INI_PERDIR*](http://php.net/configuration.changes.modes)); you can only remove them:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

For further information see [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling).

Comment: I really think this code should also `ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', false);` in order to prevent another library that was also concerned about striping input values from removing them again.

Comment: @gnarf: That would be sweet but unfortunately it doesn't work that way, if you try `ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', 0)` you will get `false` every time since this is only doable in `PHP_INI_PERDIR`.

Comment: what about if you want some slashes to remain ... such as content entered into a form that includes a fraction: 4/5 ... stripslashes would remove it

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd `stripslashes` removes backslashes.

Comment: oops  ... bad example on my part ... but my point is still good: there may be times when you have intentional backslashes that you don't want stripped out

Comment: You would only remove the backslashes if they would be added by magic quotes. That's why the code uses `get_magic_quotes_gpc`.

Comment: yep. Magic quotes can only be disabled at system level, NOT at runtime. use stripslashes, as and when needed if you dont have access to php.ini file. Most shared servers I worked all have magic quotes off. Mostly old servers have them on. Oh well.

Answer (score 5):

Magic quotes cannot be disabled at runtime, but you can use a .htaccess file in the directory to disable it.

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

The only real advantage this has is you can put it once in a directory and it works for the whole directory and subdirectories. Really nice if you need this for an application you didn't write and need to get it to work without magic quotes.

Comment: Internal Server Error.  Looks like the host isn't allowing that directive. :(

Comment: Yeah, this requires the server to be setup to allow .htaccess override. Sorry to hear it didn't work out for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have a little script for this similar to Gumbo's (but of course I like mine better :):

```
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_runtime') && get_magic_quotes_runtime())
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    array_stripslashes($_POST);
    array_stripslashes($_GET);
    array_stripslashes($_COOKIES);
}

function array_stripslashes(&$array) {
    if(is_array($array))
        while(list($key) = each($array))
            if(is_array($array[$key]))
                array_stripslashes($array[$key]);
            else
                $array[$key] = stripslashes($array[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Very useful as temporary solution before 5.3 update (vith default config of this directive). It does not require any other code modifications. Nice. Thank you.

Comment: ... but what about the situation where you are POSTing content that includes slashes that are SUPPOSED to be there, and you don't want them removed?

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd: Handled. Slashes are only stripped if magic_quotes_gpc is on, so in your situation the slashes will have been themselves quoted and will be converted back to unquoted slashes by this code.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for PHP 5.3+:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1)
{
    $_GET = json_decode(stripslashes(preg_replace('~\\\(?:0|a|b|f|n|r|t|v)~', '\\\$0', json_encode($_GET, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT))), true);
    $_POST = json_decode(stripslashes(preg_replace('~\\\(?:0|a|b|f|n|r|t|v)~', '\\\$0', json_encode($_POST, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT))), true);
    $_COOKIE = json_decode(stripslashes(preg_replace('~\\\(?:0|a|b|f|n|r|t|v)~', '\\\$0', json_encode($_COOKIE, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT))), true);
    $_REQUEST = json_decode(stripslashes(preg_replace('~\\\(?:0|a|b|f|n|r|t|v)~', '\\\$0', json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT))), true);
}
```

Handles keys, values and multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: This works, but it will also remove the slashes from other escaped characters, such as \r and \n, becoming "r" and "n" in the value.

Comment: @Brian E: Thank you for your feedback, you're right - I missed this big detail!

Comment: @Brian E: I've posted a possible fix in https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/issues/1#issuecomment-1039664.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done at runtime :(