# Avoiding slashes added by jQuery serialize()

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery to serialize a form and then POST it via ajax to the back-end to be saved to MySQL.

I've run into a problem where, for text fields containing quotation marks " and ', jQuery's .serialize() adds an escaping slash, which gets POSTed.

For Example:
' Monitor Size: 22" ' is being saved as ' Monitor Size: 22\" '. These slashes also accumulate as the field is further edited and re-saved, so that it eventually might look like 'Monitor Size: 22\\\\\\" '.

I could remove all back-slashes when processing the $_POST in PHP, but that would also remove any back-slashes that the user might have legitimately entered.

Is there another way to avoid this somehow?

Ideas Much Appreciated!

Comment: Other than fix your PHP settings to not add them in the first place?

Comment: Yikes. So *this* is how so many sites get simultaneously broken by reproducing slashes/escapes, and *also* still remain vulnerable to all sorts of SQL injection hijinks... I just hope you know why those slashes are being added, and know what to do with the resulting strings once they are removed, before feeding them to your SQL

Comment: jQuery **does not do this** -- `>>> $("<form><input name='test' value='&quot;test&quot;' /></form>").serialize();` -- result:
`"test=%22test%22"`

Comment: DB management is handled by Zend Framework, where, as far as I could tell, the DB inputs are automatically sanitized. I hope so?

Comment: E. - Yes - ZF will use the correct escaping method for database sanitation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would bet that it's not jQuery doing it, but the PHP server you're using has [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.

So either disable magic quotes, or strip the slashes yourself before saving to the DB

Comment: Rather - Don't double escape your slashes while adding to db...  Stripping them entirely is like painting a bullseye on your chest.

Comment: @gnarf: you should use the relevant DB escaping function, e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string` when writing queries.

Comment: @Andy E - Right- hence not passing an already escaped version therefore 'double escaping' (boo magic quotes) -- Also for reference [SO: How can I disable PHP magic quotes at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153741)

Comment: Both stripslashes and disabling magic quotes solved the issue. I have chosen to just disable magic quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please check stripslashes() function of PHP...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if user puts in a 'legitimate' backslash it gets escaped as well, so stripslashes() should do it's job.

Comment: Yes, tested & verified. Thanks!