# How not to add backslashes into json data with parse_str

Tags: php, json, php-5.3

Why **backslashes** are added into **json data** when `parse_str` is used? For instance,

```
# Get the query string.
$string_query = 'type={"page":"page"}';

# Parse the string into an array &array_query.
parse_str($string_query, $array_query);

var_dump($array_query);
```

result in my localhost (which is the data I am after),

```
array
  'type' => string '{"page":"page"}' (length=15)
```

but in the live server,

```
array(1) { ["type"]=> string(19) "{\"page\":\"page\"}" }
```

How can I not to add the backslashes into json data?

Comment: Is magic quotes enabled?

Comment: yes it is - just checked. how do I disable the  magic quotes?

Comment: I would guess magic quotes is turned on so php is inserting slashes before everything which needs to be escaped

Comment: php ini file just needs to be edited

Comment: oh I can't edit the php ini file as it is the live server. can I do it in .htaccess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable PHP magic quotes at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153741/how-can-i-disable-php-magic-quotes-at-runtime)

Comment: I don't think so... I may be wrong but to my knowledge edit the php.ini and restart apache -- it will maybe cause 2 seconds of down time.. not a big deal

Answer (score 0):

a simply solution,

```
# Get the query string.
$string_query = 'type={"page":"page"}';

# Parse the string into an array &array_query.
parse_str($string_query, $query_array);


// Strip slashes from an array.
function strip_magic_quotes($array)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        function stripslashes_array($array)
        {
            return is_array($array) ? array_map('stripslashes_array', $array) : stripslashes($array);
        }
        return stripslashes_array($array);
    }
    return $array;
}

$query_array = strip_magic_quotes($query_array);

var_dump($query_array);
```